# Obtener Calendario de meses y Años en c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, mvc

Vengo a plantear la siguiente problemática dada 2 fechas en c#, quisiera obtener una DataTable con el mes y año, es decir por ejemplo como fecha inicial tengo 01/01/2020 y fecha final el día hoy 16/03/2021, me gustaría tener el resultado como se muestra en la siguiente imagen.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el código de mi controlador por el momento es este

```
 public ActionResult CalculaCuotas(bool checkResp)
      {
         var date = DateTime.Now;
         DataTable Calendario = new DataTable();
         if (checkResp == true)
         {
             var prestamosvigentes = db.Prestamo.Where(p => p.Status == checkResp);
             if (prestamosvigentes != null)
             {
                 foreach (var item in prestamosvigentes)
                 {                        
                     var fechaUltimoPago = db.DetalleCuota.Where(p => p.PrestamoId ==       item.PrestamoId)
                                        .OrderBy(p=>p.FechaPago).FirstOrDefault();
                    if (fechaUltimoPago == null)
                    {
                        var fechaInicial = item.Fecha;
                        var fechaFinal = date;

                        var meses = Diferencia( fechaFinal, fechaInicial);

                    }
                    
                }

            }
        }

        return View();
    }
```

Sera posible puedan dar alguna idea, de antemano muchas gracias

Comment: Pero intentaste resolverlo de alguna forma?

Comment: Hola, podrías decirme si te sirvio la solución dada

Comment: Horacio, ya lo arreglé revisa

Comment: Hola, podrías votar las respuestas que te resultaron útiles y marcar como aceptada la que más te halla gustado, gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La respuesta de @Japv funciona correctamente, pero aquí tienes otra alternativa si deseas utilizar esta función

```
public IEnumerable<Tuple<int, int>> ObtenerCalendario(DateTime fechaInicio, DateTime fechaFinal)
{
    DateTime iterador;
    DateTime limite;
    ///Controlar la fecha estén en el orden correcto
    if (fechaFinal > fechaInicio)
    {
        iterador = new DateTime(fechaInicio.Year, fechaInicio.Month, 1);
        limite = fechaFinal;
    }
    else
    {
        iterador = new DateTime(fechaFinal.Year, fechaFinal.Month, 1);
        limite = fechaInicio;
    }
    ///Crear el ciclo, que generará los meses y anos
    while (iterador <= limite)
    {
        yield return Tuple.Create(iterador.Month, iterador.Year);
        iterador = iterador.AddMonths(1);
    }
}
```

Y para usarla e insertar los datos en el `DataTable` harías esto

```
 DataTable dt = new DataTable();
 dt.Columns.Add("Mes", typeof(int));
 dt.Columns.Add("Ano", typeof(int));
 var fechaInicial = Convert.ToDateTime("01/12/2020");
 var fechaFinal = Convert.ToDateTime("18/03/2021");
 DataRow dr;
 var calendario = ObtenerCalendario(fechaInicial, fechaFinal);
 ///Insertar las filas a la tabla...
 foreach (var cal in calendario)
 {
      dr = dt.NewRow();
      dr.BeginEdit();
      dr["Mes"] = cal.Item1;
      dr["Ano"] = cal.Item2;
      dr.EndEdit();
      dt.Rows.Add(dr);
 }

 ///Al llegar aquí ya tu DataTable tiene todos los datos, 
 ///para usarlos como desees
```

Al final el resultado queda así

[image: Resultado]

Answer (score 0):

```
int mesInicial = fechaInicial.Month;
int annoInicial = fechaInicial.Year;
int mesFinal = fechaFinal.Month;
int annoFinal = fechaFinal.Year;
bool fin = false;

while(!fin)
{
   //Insertar en el DataTable el mesInicial y el annoInicial
   
   //Después de insertar en el DataTable vendría este código 

   fin = (mesInicial == mesFinal) && (annoInicial == annoFinal);
   mesInicial= (mesInicial % 12) + 1;

   if(mesInicial == 1)
   {
      annoInicial += 1;
   }          
}
```

Se declaran **4 variables** de tipo entero para guardar el mes de la fecha inicial, el mes de la fecha final, el año de la fecha inicial y el año de la fecha final.

Además se declara la **variable booleana fin** la cual nos indicará cuando se detendrá el **ciclo while**.

Posteriormente se va a ejecutar un **ciclo while** que se va a ejecutar mientras la **variable fin** sea **false**.

Ya dentro del ciclo guardamos los valores del mes inicial y el año inicial en el **DataTable**. Posteriormente hacemos un cálculo usando el **operador %** el cual devuelve el resto de una división, ejemplo:

1 % 12 = 1

2 % 12 = 2

...

11 % 12 = 11

12 % 12 = 0

Y después se reinicia todo y empieza el mismo proceso descrito anteriormente.

Eso es lo qué pasa en el código dentro del **ciclo while**, se va incrementando el mes y cuando llega a **12** empieza el mes de nuevo en **1** y se incrementa el año. Analiza el código y adáptalo a tus necesidades.